Why would a search warrant say that the items to search for were the following: hair, fibers, clothing, rope wire, and binding material?
The search warrant listed the address to be searched, and also listed that any outbuildings and vehicles on the curtilage of the property could be searched for the following items:

Hair, fibers, clothing, rope, wire, and binding material

They were supposedly looking for a phone, but that was not listed on the warrant anywhere. Nothing but the previous stated items were listed on the warrant. They did take several things, but they didn't take a phone.
What exactly were they looking for? How could this be OK?

There is no way or magical crystal ball to explain why the police was looking to get exactly those materials in a search. The explanation is: that was what the authority issuing the search warrant allowed them to search for after the requested to search for things. Where did you get your "supposedly" from? Maybe that would be a good source to ask, they seem better informed than wild guesses on the internet.

This is not a question about law. This is a question about police investigation methods.

canada
The search warrant must specify the "thing" to be searched for a seized.

While the items authorized for seizure do not need to be listed with “scrupulous exactitude”, enough detail is required that the searching officers are both guided and limited in their actions.
R. v Nguyen, 2017 ONSC 1341, para. 99.

The description "must not be so broad and vague as to give the searching officers carte blanche to rummage through the premises of the target."
So the search warrant would list those items because the investigators were searching for those items.
You assert that they were "supposedly looking for a phone."
I have no idea where this supposition comes from. If they were looking for a phone, this is not reflected in the search warrant. Indeed, as you say, they did not seize a phone in this hypothetical.
You ask "what exactly were they looking for?" The answer is in the warrant:

Hair, fibers, clothing, rope, wire, and binding material;


yes so what do we do?? i mean we assumed this is about breaking and entering or theft, but it appears as if they're looking for evidence on some kind of murder or something, and that is crazy sounding to me!!! we didn't do anything to begin with, but this is absolutely absurd.

What happens if the police, during their search for hair and fibers, come across e.g. a bag with 50kg of heroin, or a barn full of jewelry and electronics? I.e. items highly suggestive of criminal activity, but not what they had on the warrant.

@StrangerToKindness Welcome. There are other Q&A on this site addressing that: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/13714/46948 In general, comments are not the place to ask new questions.

If they were "supposed to be looking for a phone", then perhaps that item was so important to the crime being investigated that it was obvious to all that even the dumbest criminal would have thrown it away beforehand.
There's a scene in a film (I think maybe starring Harrison Ford) where his wife asks "why weren't they searching for the murder weapon?" to which Harrison Ford replied "they think I'm a murderer, not stupid - no one would bring a murder weapon back home after clubbing someone to death".

This doesn't answer any of the questions.
